# Wireshark: Parsing packets

Tags: c, network-programming, wireshark

I am wondering how does Wireshark parse 802.11 packets.

For example, A probe request packet has a sequence number: 2327.

In the packet details, in hexadecimal it is "70 91", while in ASCII it is "p."

Then how does wireshark get the value "2327" from the packet? Is there a similar example in C?

Comment: The `.` is simply a placeholder: `0x91` isn't a printable [iso-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso-8859-1#Codepage_layout) character; it isn't in any of the [iso](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859#Table) tables. It isn't a legal [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) character either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 802.11 Sequence Control field is a 16 bit little-endian field that contains two subfields - the upper 12 bits contain the Sequence Number, and the lower 4 bits contain the Fragment Number.  In this case:

- Sequence Control = 0x9170
- Sequence Number = 0x917 = 2327 decimal
- Fragment Number = 0x0 = 0

Answer (score 0):

@caf was right,anyway i post the code on how i extract the Sequence Number..

```
//this is the subfields
 typedef struct seqctl_subfields
 {
    unsigned fragment:4;
    unsigned seq_num:12;
 };

 struct seqctl_fields *se = (struct seqctl_fields*)p->sc // where p is a struct of the 802.11 header,p->sc points to the sequence control field of the 802.11 header
 std::cout << se->seq_num << std::endl;
```

Comment: thank you, for reply. Can you give code for python with Scapy(Dot11), It will be very helpful.